# Function that checks if a tree has only odd numbers C++

Tags: c++, tree

So, we have a tree with nodes that store numbers.

```
{
    int data;
    treeNode* child;
    treeNode* sibling;

    treeNode(int data) :data(data), child(nullptr), sibling(nullptr) {}
    treeNode() {}
};
```

I'm trying to check if every node stores an odd number.
Example:

```
           1 -- 3
          / \
         5   7
```

Here **1** is the root and the others are its **children** and the function is meant to return true.

```
private:
bool isOdd(treeNode* node)const
    {
        if (!node) //I think the problem might be here but I don't really know how to fix it
            return true;
        if (node->data % 2 == 0)
            return false;
        return isOdd(node->child);
        return isOdd(node->sibling);
    }
public:
bool isOdd()const
    {
        if (root->data % 2 == 0)
            return false;

        return isOdd(root->child);
    }
```

As shown above, I'm using recursion, but I'm willing to use iterative approach too.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You want to check if **all** nodes are odd, but you actually check whether **either** left child or right child is odd.

Comment: Code after `return` will *never* be executed. You want a different logical operator than OR.

Comment: The solution is as @Yunnosch suggested. Thanks!

Comment: I'm using this tree for a certain assignment. I also have an insertion method that allows the user to put new node on a given level as a sibling or as a child(depends on the level)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After this line

```
return isOdd(node->child);
```

the follwoing one is ingored, because as Yksisarvinen has commented, after one `return` statement has been executed, the function is done, nothing else will be executed.
I.e.

```
return isOdd(node->sibling);
```

will not influence the result, i.e. the sibling is ignored.

In order to always return something influeced by both parts, you need a logic operation

```
return (isOdd(node->sibling) && isOdd(node->child));
```

On the other hand your code

```
if (!node) return true;
```

seems fine to me. If you analyse a pointer which points to nothing (without dereferencing it, good) then it makes sense to say "Nothing" cannot break the "all odd", so returning true makes sense to me.